# How to sum columns of a dynamically created range of cells in Excel

Tags: java, excel, export-to-excel, excel-formula, jxls

There are a number of rows created using a jxls forEach loop in an Excel spreadsheet. Within each of these rows, there are a set of columns that are also dynamically created with a forEach. So essentially one cell turns into a range of a few cells out and a few cells down. At the bottom of each of the generated columns of cells I want a sum formula to sum up the column. If I put SUM(C3) in the cell that turns into lots of cells I get an error that you can't SUM(C3:E3:C5:E5) or something to that effect.

According to the official page: http://jxls.sourceforge.net/reference/formulas.html , jxls is clever enough to adjust your sum when the cell turns into a range going down, and also across, but not both.

I must also mention that I would like the forumlae to stick to the cells and not just produce the sum so if I edit a cell above, it will update in the total below.

Could anyone help me with this issue?

[image: Here's an example of what I'm talking about. I know there are mistakes because I changed some of the text but hopefully you get the idea.]

Also, using r1c1 referencing hasn't worked because when I export the default reference of A1 is set in excel and will be set that way for anyone who uses this. I tried setting a startup macro to use r1c1 cell referencing but to no avail.

I solved it using the following formula : =SUM(D13:INDIRECT("R[-1]C",0)) where initial & final cell can be addressed using indirect()

Comment: Have you solved this problem yet?

Comment: No, never solved it. I think it was impossible due to the limitations of jxls :(

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify what your are seeking a solution to, if I understand correctly, you were seeking a formula to add the ranges of c3:e3 and also (in the same formula) c5:e5?  if so, try:

=sum(c3:e3)+sum(c5:e5)

Is this what you were attempting?

Comment: No, I want the formula =SUM(C3:C5) in cell C6, =SUM(D3:D5) in cell D6, and =SUM(E3:E5) in cell E6.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:

first, add a org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference object to your transformer beans:

```
Map<String, Object> beans = new HashMap<>();
...
beans.put("cellRef", new CellReference(0,0));
...
Workbook wb = transformer.transformXLS(xlsInputStream, beans);
```

Then, in your xls template use the formula:

```
${hssfCell.setCellFormula("SUM(" + cellRef.convertNumToColString(hssfCell.columnIndex) + "2:" + cellRef.convertNumToColString(hssfCell.columnIndex) + hssfCell.rowIndex + ")")}
```